# Huawei G300 not fast enough for Google Racer

Tags: performance, ram, huawei-g300

So on my Nexus 7 (currently clocked at 1300mb RAM) Google Racer works fine. However, when I use it on my Huawei Ascend G300 (only clocked at ~30mb less RAM) it says it is too slow.

This doesn't really make any sense? They have almost identical RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of RAM is not the main factor that determines how smoothly a game runs. The other items on the spec sheet are just as important:

- What model of CPU it has (ARM 11, Cortex-A8, Cortex-A9, Cortex-A15, &c)
- How many CPU cores there are (some games benefit more from having multiple cores than others)
- What clock speed the CPU runs at (measured in GHz)
- What model of GPU it has (e.g Mali-400MP4)
- What clock speed the GPU runs at (measured in GHz)

and there are many other important factors you probably won't find written down anywhere, such as the clock speed of the RAM, what kind of memory controller it has, and the size of the CPU and GPU caches. The software makes a big difference too: for example, if the power management driver (supplied by the manufacturer) is inefficient, the CPU and GPU may spend most of their time running more slowly than the rated clock speed.

In addition, the pixel size of the display makes a big difference. For example, if you made a tablet with the exact same hardware as a Nexus 7 but a 1080p display instead of a 720p display, you'd find many games would run much slower on this device, simply because there are more than twice as many pixels to process and store in memory.

One of the reasons that unbranded devices are so cheap is that the manufacturers often invest in the 'headline' specs, but then skimp on the other components, or use inefficient software. For example, it's commonplace to use a GPU that looks good on paper, but cripple it by only giving it a very slow connection to the device's RAM, through a cheap memory controller.

The only way you can really tell how smooth your games will run is by measuring on the device: ideally with the game you're interested in, but more commonly using a *benchmark* such as GLBenchmark that represents an 'average' game. That's why review sites like to include benchmark figures as a big part of the review of a new device.

Answer (score 2):

Running a game smoothly does depend on RAM as well as the capability of your processor and more significantly the graphics chipset employed on your device. Compare all three of these factors and you'll understand hopefully why your Huawei G300 doesn't run the game of your choice as well as your Nexus 7.